# How to Prevent Postman Desktop from Encoding OATH Consumer Key

Tags: postman

I am trying to make the switch from the deprecated Chrome version of Postman to the desktop version. However, when using OAUTH authentication the consumer key is URL encoded in the header with the desktop version, but it is not encoded when using the Chrome version. Therefore, the authentication with the desktop version fails whereas, it succeeds with the Chrome version. The consumer secret I am using requires a "!" In the desktop version, the authentication fails because postman url encodes the "!" when it updates the authorization header. Is there a way to prevent this from being encoded in the desktop version?

In other words, I need the consumer key to be "oauth_consumer_key=foo!bar" in the Authorization header, not "oauth_consumer_key=foo%21bar"

Answer (score 0):

I submitted a ticket with Postman and it is now a confirmed Bug #4300.